# Keyboard navigation in listview having multiple focusable element

Tags: android, listview, keyboard

I have a Android ListView which can have contains different types of listItem.
Some of the listitems have multiple focusable element themselves. 
I am looking for a way to be able to navigate list using hardware keyboard as well as be able to select focusable elements inside listitem and navigate among them.

For example in below image all of the listItem have multiple buttons. So when I open my Activity, I should be able to navigate through listitem using keyboard up and down arrow.

[image]

But when I press Enter ( or D-PAD), then focus should go to first button inside that listItem. After that I should be able to navigate through all buttons using arrow keys

[image]

I am able to achieve first case when I set  focusable false for all the buttons and set listView.setItemsCanFocus(false) on listView itself.

I have tried setting the setFocusable(false) before returning the view from adapter and then handling them in list OnItemClickListener

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {          
                View v = listView.getChildAt(position);
                v.setFocusable(true);
                v.requestFocus();
                Button b1 = (Button)(listView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.butt1));
                Button b2 = (Button)(listView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.butt1));                   
                b1.setFocusable(true);
                b2.setFocusable(true);                  
                b1.requestFocus();
            }
    });
```

But It is also not giving focus to button.

Comment: You got the solution?